# How to make a query to GROUP BY x DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

The following SELECT statement

```
select * 
from messages 
where receiverID = '5' 
group BY senderID 
order by id DESC
```

database:

```
id | senderID | receiverID | message
1  |  245     |    5       | test 1
2  |  89      |    5       | test 2
3  |  79      |    5       | test 3
4  |  245     |    5       | test 4
5  |  245     |    5       | test 5
```

For senderID=245 I expected to return the row with id=5 , but it dosent it returns row with id=1, but i want the last row. How to achieve that ?

returns:

```
id | senderID | receiverID | message
1  |  245     |    5       | test 1
2  |  89      |    5       | test 2
3  |  79      |    5       | test 3
```

---

Ohh I made it :D

so this is the code that worked,for anyone with similar question

```
     SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM messages WHERE
 receiverID = '5' ORDER BY id DESC) AS m GROUP BY senderID ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? Perhaps an example list result you're trying to achieve

Comment: Why do you use `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: i use GROUP BY because i want the last row of each senderID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but it sounds to me like you want:

```
select max(id), 
       senderId, 
       max(receiverId), 
       max(message)
from messages 
where receiverID = '5' 
group BY senderID 
order by id DESC
```

Note that you need to include message into your aggregate as well, otherwise you'll get unpredicatable results (other DBMS wouldn't allow leaving out the `max(message)` but MySQL will simply return a random row from the group).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You have to do something like:

```
[...] WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` WHERE `receiverID` = '5')
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd consider a subquery, something along the lines of this should do the job for you

```
SELECT messagesOrdered.*
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM messages 
  WHERE receiverID = '5' 
  ORDER BY id DESC
) AS messagesOrdered
GROUP BY senderID
```

You may wish to check  what keys you have set up depending on how large the table is.

The problem with using MAX is that if you use MAX on the `id` field then it will get the number you are looking for, however using MAX on another field does not get the data that matches that id.  Using the subquery method, the inner query is doing the sorting and then the GROUP on the outside will group based on the order of rows in the inner query.

Comment: This almost worked .. yes it gets the last row of the senderID but the rows where senderID have only 1 row, after the group appear before the grouped rows

Comment: Ah I was about to comment that you can order the outside query still, wasn't 100% clear on what precisely you were after.  Glad to see it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages m
JOIN 
( SELECT senderID, MAX(id) AS last
  FROM messages 
  WHERE receiverID = '5' 
  GROUP BY senderID ) mg
ON m.id = mg.last
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes mine :)

```
select m1.* from messages m1
left join messages m2
on m1.senderid = m2.senderid and m1.id < m2.id
where m2.id is null and receiverID = '5'
```

Given your example this would return:

```
+----+----------+------------+---------+
| ID | SENDERID | RECEIVERID | MESSAGE |
+----+----------+------------+---------+
|  2 |       89 |          5 | test 2  |
|  3 |       79 |          5 | test 3  |
|  5 |      245 |          5 | test 5  |
+----+----------+------------+---------+
```